# How to Sum same product's product _Volume value at with ORM-Query

Tags: python, django, orm

I need to sum all different product's "product_volume" in one for this my model is

```
class Product(BaseModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='product_category')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hs_code = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/product/%Y/%M/', null=True, blank=True)
    production_unit = models.ForeignKey(MeasurementUnit, related_name='product_unit', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Production(BaseModel, models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='production_product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district = models.ForeignKey(DistrictLevel, related_name='production_district', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    production_volume = models.FloatField()
    production_year = models.ForeignKey(FiscalYear, related_name='production_year', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    seasons = models.ManyToManyField(Season)
```

Here, I'm trying to do is that, sum of the product_volume of a product is like,
`product1, product_volume=20`
`product2, product_volume = 40`
`product1, product_volume = 60`

in my table i need to show

`product1, product_volume = 80`
`product2, product_volume = 40`

Here is my table
[image]

I'm getting result by using for loop but, is there any better solution for this using ORM.

sorry for my English, I'm little weak in English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Sum` aggregation function [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#sum) to annotate the sum of the field:

```
products = Product.objects.annotate(total_production_volume=Sum('production_product__production_volume'))

for product in products:
    print(product.name, product.total_production_volume)
```

Here `production_product` is the related name you have set for the field (this name is quite weird `product.production_product` doesn't feel very good right? Perhaps the related name would have been better off as `productions`), and we simply used `__` to separate it from the field name that we want to sum on.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't have idea to use related_name in Sum function. It works.